# Cytoscape expand collapse with React

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

I am  using react-cytoscapejs. I am importing also COSEBilkent layout. I would like to have an opportunity to expand and collapse nodes on click. So on click on node called 'parent' I would like to hide its children(I am starting with the simplest possible example but I am aiming at something much more complicated). I am having reference to cy core in useEffect but I am nnot sure if this is right with this lib, and how to enforce expected behaviour: As a result in future i would like to have a graph with options like this in the example http://ivis-at-bilkent.github.io/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse/demo.html

My codesnippet:

```
import Cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import COSEBilkent from 'cytoscape-cose-bilkent';
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import CytoscapeComponent from 'react-cytoscapejs';
import expandCollapse from 'cytoscape-expand-collapse';

expandCollapse(Cytoscape);
Cytoscape.use(COSEBilkent);

const Test = ({}) => {
  const [cy, setCy] = useState(null);
  const elements = [
    { data: { id: 'parent', label: 'parent' } },
    { data: { id: 'one', label: 'Node1' } },
    { data: { id: 'two', label: 'Node2' } },
    { data: { source: 'parent', target: 'two', label: 'Edge from parent to two' } },
    { data: { source: 'parent', target: 'one', label: 'Edge from parent to one' } }
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cy) {
      cy.expandCollapse();
 
    }
  });
  const layout = { name: 'cose-bilkent' };

  return (
    <CytoscapeComponent
      cy={cy => {
        setCy(cy);
      }}
      layout={layout}
      elements={elements}
      style={{ width: '600px', height: '600px' }}
    />
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: You'd need a ref to do expandCollapse.

Comment: ref of cytoscapeComponent?

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be late for you. As said in the comments,it would be better to have a ref for your cytoscape so that you directly manipulate the DOM, you can do without also.

```
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  ready: function () {
    console.log("INSIDE READY");
    var api = this.expandCollapse({
      layoutBy: {
        name: "concentric",
        animate: "end",
        randomize: false,
        fit: true
      },
      fisheye: true,
      animate: false,
      undoable: false,

      //below keys are in regard to apperance of icons/style of expand-collapse
      expandCollapseCuePosition: "top-left",
      expandCollapseCueSize: 12,
      expandCollapseCueLineSize: 20,
      expandCueImage: "./imgs/expand-alt-solid.svg",
      collapseCueImage: "./imgs/compress-alt-solid.svg",
      expandCollapseCueSensitivity: 1,
      edgeTypeInfo: "edgeType",
      groupEdgesOfSameTypeOnCollapse: true,
      allowNestedEdgeCollapse: false,
      zIndex: 999,
      cueEnabled: true
  }
   //provide your style object with selectors here.For example
     style: [
    //CORE
    {
      selector: "core",
      css: {
        //"active-bg-opacity": "", //The opacity of the active background indicator.
        "active-bg-size": 10, //The size of the active background indicator.

        "selection-box-color": "blue" //The background colour of the selection box used for drag selection.


      }]
})
```

Use of expandCollapse library shall take care of the rendering.
Manipulate the layout for your desired look.

You need to provide this above code inside an useEffect with 'cy' as your dependency.

In terms of using a ref, you would need a div pointing to our ref :

```
const containerRef = useRef(null);

//Inside return, render the div
 <div ref={containerRef}id="cy"/>
```